# Recursive loop over Symfony form children

Tags: php, recursion, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to build a method to turn Symfony form errors into a multidimensional array which can be serialized.

Currently I only have a form within a form (a fieldset type). I have created a new system for embedding N number of forms within forms. I need to be able to traverse all the children that have errors to populate the `$errors` array.

I need to keep track of the depth or how far I have traversed.

For example a form within in a form would be `$errors[depth1][depth2]['message']`. A form with multiple embedded forms (say up to 5) would be `$errors[depth1][depth2][depth3][depth4][depth5]['message']` `$errors[depth1][depth2]` e.t.c.

**NB:** `[depth(N)]` would be replaced with the current form name.

What's the cleanest way to do this.

This is my current function that gets fieldsets but I was it to be able to get any errors regardless of depth and keep position (keys) intact?

```
private static function getFieldSetErrors(Form $form, &$errors)
    {
        foreach ($form->all() as $formField) {
            if ($formField->getConfig()->getType()->getInnerType() instanceof FieldsetComponentType) {
                // ...then loop over the fields to extract any errors.
                foreach ($formField as $element) {
                    foreach ($element->getErrors() as $error) {
                        $errors[$formField->getName()][$element->getName()]['message'] = $error->getMessage();
                        $errors[$formField->getName()][$element->getName()]['messageTemplate'] = $error->getMessageTemplate();
                        $errors[$formField->getName()][$element->getName()]['messagePluralization'] = $error->getMessagePluralization();
                        $errors[$formField->getName()][$element->getName()]['messageParameters'] = $error->getMessageParameters();
                        $errors[$formField->getName()][$element->getName()]['cause'] = $errors[$formField->getName()][$element->getName()];
                        if ($errorCause = $error->getCause()) {
                            $errors[$formField->getName()][$element->getName()]['cause']['plural'] = $errorCause->getPlural();
                            $errors[$formField->getName()][$element->getName()]['cause']['propertyPath'] = $errorCause->getPropertyPath();
                            $errors[$formField->getName()][$element->getName()]['cause']['invalidValue'] = $errorCause->getInvalidValue();
                            $errors[$formField->getName()][$element->getName()]['cause']['constraint'] = serialize($errorCause->getConstraint());
                            $errors[$formField->getName()][$element->getName()]['cause']['code'] = $errorCause->getCode();
                            $errors[$formField->getName()][$element->getName()]['cause']['cause'] = $errorCause->getCause();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It may look something like:

```
private static function getFieldErrorsRecursively(Form $form, &$errors, $position = [])
    {
        foreach ($form as $child) {
            $fieldsArray = $child->getConfig()->getOptions()['fields'] ?? [];
            if (count($fieldsArray) === 0) {
                if (!$child->isValid()) {
                    foreach ($child->getErrors() as $error) {
                        $errors[$child->getName()]['message'] = $error->getMessage();
                        $errors[$child->getName()]['messageTemplate'] = $error->getMessageTemplate();
                        $errors[$child->getName()]['messagePluralization'] = $error->getMessagePluralization();
                        $errors[$child->getName()]['messageParameters'] = $error->getMessageParameters();
                        $errors[$child->getName()]['cause'] = $errors[$child->getName()];
                        if ($errorCause = $error->getCause()) {
                            $errors[$child->getName()]['cause']['plural'] = $errorCause->getPlural();
                            $errors[$child->getName()]['cause']['propertyPath'] = $errorCause->getPropertyPath();
                            $errors[$child->getName()]['cause']['invalidValue'] = $errorCause->getInvalidValue();
                            $errors[$child->getName()]['cause']['constraint'] = serialize($errorCause->getConstraint());
                            $errors[$child->getName()]['cause']['code'] = $errorCause->getCode();
                            $errors[$child->getName()]['cause']['cause'] = $errorCause->getCause();
                        }
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            } elseif (count($fieldsArray) > 0) {
                self::getFieldErrorsRecursively($child, $errors, $child->getName());

                if (count($errors) > 0) {
                    return true;
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Don't (keep track). Build a recursive function that gets called with the array and calls itself with the nested array. If you pass by reference, you can always use `$errors['cause']..`

Comment: I guess I have to keep track of the position but cause when I apply them back again I need to know how deep in the form to when applying the error back to the it's field of origin.

Comment: Maybe I don't need to track if I apply them back by just searching for the field that matches the original cause field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Symfony provides a function for this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html#accessing-form-errors)

```
// a FormErrorIterator instance representing the form tree structure
$errors = $form->getErrors(true, false);
```

Comment: That's lovely it neatens up the code for sure. Though I think I am still going to have to write something recursive as you cannot serialize the output of that function because it contains closures.